# Javascript - deleting a row by id

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm currently trying to delete rows in a html table
each row has three values. The third value is a checkbox that is used to checked rows that should be deleted. After clicking delete row(s) button all checked rows should be deleted. The problem is the code I have do nothing when I click the button and no row is being deleted.

```js
var counter = 0;

function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  table.setAttribute("border", "1");
  var row = table.insertRow(counter);
  row.setAttribute("id", "row" + counter);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("url").value;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("name", "shouldDelete");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", counter);
  cell3.appendChild(checkbox);

  counter = counter + 1;

}

function deleteRows() {
  var checkedItems = document.getElementsByName("shouldDelete");
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
    if (checkedItems[i].checked) {
      var row = document.getElementById("row" + i);
      table.removeChild(row);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Tell me your URL:</h1>
<p>Add a new row</p>
<p>
  <label>Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</p>
<p>
  <label>Your URL:</label>
  <input type="text" id="url">
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add to bottom</button>
  <button onclick="deleteRows()">Delete selected row(s)</button>
</p>
<hr>
<table id="table"></table>
```

**THIS IS HOW I SOLVE IT:**

```
function deleteRows() {
            var checkedItems = document.getElementsByName("shouldDelete");
            var ids = [];
            for(var i=0;i<checkedItems.length;i++) {
                if(checkedItems[i].checked) {
                    ids.push("row"+checkedItems[i].id)
                }
            }

            for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
                var row = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
                var parent = row.parentNode;
                parent.removeChild(row);
                counter = counter-1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show your html code?

Answer (score 2):

Catch it

since you have a row's id you can simply select it, then select it's parent and make a deletion.

Your code didn't work because in a table there were a tbody tag or something like that, so `table` var doesn't directly contain a `row`.

```
     function deleteRows() {

        var checkedItems = document.getElementsByName("shouldDelete");
        for(var i=0;i<checkedItems.length;i++) {
            if(checkedItems[i].checked) {
                var row = document.getElementById("row"+i);

                var parent = row.parentNode

                parent.removeChild(row)
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Ok, i fixed it. You need to store rownames before cycle through each and remove, because once you remove an item, you remove a checkbox too, and it start to point you on a wrong element.

```
function deleteRows() {

        var deletionRowIds = []

        var checkedItems = document.querySelectorAll('[name="shouldDelete"]:checked');

        console.log(checkedItems)

        for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++){
            deletionRowIds.push('row' + checkedItems[i].id);
        }


        deletionRowIds.forEach(function(rowId){ 


            var row = document.getElementById(rowId)
          var rowParent = row.parentNode

          rowParent.removeChild(row)
        });

    }
```

Comment: it does not fully work. there was a problem when running this code. after i added 6 rows and trying to delete them all. only three rows were deleted

Comment: Just a pointer that you can add. Instead of looping on `checkboxes`, you should loop over table's rows.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are removing using  `table.removeChild(row);` is not actually a child of that table, the child of table is `tbody` tag.
So use:

```
table.firstElementChild.removeChild(row);
```

instead of:

```
table.removeChild(row);
```

Comment: There may be multiple table section elements (tbodies, tfoot, thead) so simpler to just do `row.parentNode.removeChild(row)`. ;-)

Comment: My current focus was this problem only ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to remove rows:

```js
function deleteRows() {
  // Fetch table from where rows needs to be removed
  var table = document.querySelector('#table');

  // Get all rows to loop over them
  var trs = table.rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

    // fetch checkbox and check if is selected
    if (trs[i].querySelector('[type=checkbox]').checked) {

      // Remove row
      table.deleteRow(i)

      // Update counter so inserting does not gives issues again
      counter--;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var counter = 0;

function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  table.setAttribute("border", "1");
  var row = table.insertRow(counter);
  row.setAttribute("id", "row" + counter);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("url").value;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("name", "shouldDelete");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", counter);
  cell3.appendChild(checkbox);

  counter = counter + 1;
}

function deleteRows() {
  var table = document.querySelector('#table');
  var trs = table.rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    if (trs[i].querySelector('[type=checkbox]').checked) {
      table.deleteRow(i)
      counter--;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Tell me your URL:</h1>
<p>Add a new row</p>
<p>
  <label>Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</p>
<p>
  <label>Your URL:</label>
  <input type="text" id="url">
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add to bottom</button>
  <button onclick="deleteRows()">Delete selected row(s)</button>
</p>
<hr>
<table id="table"></table>
```

---

#### Edit

As rightly pointed out by @[RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg), we should use `table.rows` and then we can use `table.deleteRow(index)` instead of entire element.

Comment: You can also get the rows as `table.rows`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG i didn't know this. jQuery had spoiled me. I'll update on sometime. Thanks

Comment: @RobG Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this please try below code :

```
function deletetableRow(tableID)  {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID).tBodies[0];
    var rowCount = table.rows.length; // it's return total number of rows

    for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[8].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
         }
    }
```

}

and call this function on delete button click like this :

Here, "datatable" is a table id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteRows() {
  var checkedItems = document.getElementsByName("shouldDelete");
  // var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
    if (checkedItems[i].checked) {
      var row = document.getElementById("row" + i);
      row.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw my hat in the ring. ;-)

I don't know if you need the counter and IDs for other things, but they aren't needed for this so I've removed them. The input doesn't need a name either but I've left it here for posterity. Lastly, just setting an element's innerHTML is a lot simpler than adding elements through DOM methods.

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow();  // Inserts at end by default
  var cell1 = row.insertCell();
  var cell2 = row.insertCell();
  var cell3 = row.insertCell();

  cell1.textContent = document.getElementById("name").value;
  cell2.textContent = document.getElementById("url").value;
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete">';
}

// Helper, go from el up to ancestor with tagName
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  while (el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Delete rows with checked checkboxes
function deleteRows() {
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('#table input:checked'); 
  [].forEach.call(cbs, function(cb) {
      var row = upTo(cb, 'tr');
      row && row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Tell me your URL:</h1>
<p>Add a new row</p>
<p>
  <label>Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</p>
<p>
  <label>Your URL:</label>
  <input type="text" id="url">
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add to bottom</button>
  <button onclick="deleteRows()">Delete selected row(s)</button>
</p>
<hr>
<table id="table"></table>
```